# using angularjs controller that consumes a service promise inside the view

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-controller, angular-services, angular-promise

I have an controller that consumes an angularjs service promise. I have written jasmine unit tests against the controller and therefore the controller function looks like:

```
this.getTodos = function () {
    TodoService.getTodos().then(function (todos) {
        $scope.Todos = todos;
      },
        function (error) {
            // TODO: display the error pop up
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

It seems like this does not work with the view? If I change the function to be as:

```
 TodoService.getTodos().then(function (todos) {
        $scope.Todos = todos;
      },
        function (error) {
            // TODO: display the error pop up
            console.log(error);
        });
```

then it works but then I cannot test my controller function. My preferred way would be to use it as this.getTodos, this.saveTodo, this.DeleteTodo etc ....

any suggestions please?

many thanks

====>> Update

As mentioned the tests are all working but the view does not show data; seems like controller this.getTodos is not called at all. .... I am not sure how to force angular view to use controller getTodos... Tests are below:

The following jasmine tests work fine:

```
    it("Reading todos...", inject(function ($q) {

        var deferredRead = $q.defer();
        spyOn(todoServiceMock, "getTodos").and.returnValue(deferredRead.promise);
        deferredRead.resolve([{ TodoId: 10, Description: "Test", Completed: false },
        { TodoId: 11, Description: "Test", Completed: false }]);
        todoController.getTodos();
        scope.$apply();

        expect(scope.Todos.length).toBe(2);
    }));

    it("Reading todos, error...", inject(function ($q) {

        var deferredRead = $q.defer();
        spyOn(todoServiceMock, "getTodos").and.returnValue(deferredRead.promise);
        deferredRead.reject("There are no todos available!");
        todoController.getTodos();
        scope.$apply();

        expect(scope.Todos.length).toBe([]);
    }));
```

However, the view does not populate the rows ...

The view has code like:

```
<tr class="animate" ng-repeat="Todo in Todos | orderBy:'TodoId' | filter: filterTodo">
                    <td class="col-sm-1">{{Todo.TodoId}}</td>
                    <td class="col-sm-3">{{Todo.Description}}</td>
                    <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" ng-show="   {{Todo.Completed}}==true"></span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" ng-show="{{Todo.Completed}}==false"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-sm-2">
                        <a href="" ng-click="selectTodo(Todo)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Could you please add the test and the error you get in the test. A jsfiddle would be nice too

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think I didn't make my question clear enough. The tests are all working fine. But the view is not working e.g the view is not calling the controller this.getTodos function. I will update the original post.

Comment: I'm not an expert but you could try adding a $scope.apply().  But the way I do something similar is to have the factory load the data on its own, pass the factory object into the controller and have the factory broadcast a message when it has loaded the data with the controller watching for that

Answer (score 1):

Angular won't call a function from your scope if you don't tell it to call it. So, you basically have 3 choices:

1. Do as you did in your second attempt
2. Call the function in your controller when it's instantiated:

   ```
   this.getTodos = function () { ... }; // define the method
   this.getTodos(); // call it
   ```
3. Use `ng-init` in the view to call the `getTodos()` function.

Note that using the first or second technique shouldn't prevent you from unit-testing the controller. The unique difference is that your test should expect that the service call is made when the controller is *instantiated* (i.e. when `$controller('TodoController')` is called) rather than expect it to happen after it has been instantiated, when the `getTodos()` function is called.

Comment: Hi JB, Thanks for the reply. Going with option 2 resolves the problem however all my Tests will fail now. The error is "Result Message: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'promise.then') in file:///d:/rahman/angularjsandunittesting/angularjsandunittesting/scripts/app/controllers.js (line 21)" ... and line 21 is TodoService.getTodos().then(function (todos) { ... Commenting the this.getTodos(); line all the tests will run fine again. Not sure why should happen???

Comment: As I said, because now, instantiating the controller calls the service. So you should modify the beforeEach() of your test.